# How to Send the mail to multiple clients or groups using win32com.client Module in Python?

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to send the mail using **win32com.client Module** in Python. But could not come up with the proper documentation to support multiple recipients or groups to send the message.
Could someone please suggest.
I have specific requirement to work with only outlook application.

```
import win32com.client
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "I AM SUBJECT!!"
newMail.Body = "I AM IN THE BODY\nSO AM I!!!"
newMail.To = "who_to_send_to@example.com"
#newMail.CC = "moreaddresses here"
#newMail.BCC = "address"
#attachment1 = "Path to attachment no. 1"
#attachment2 = "Path to attachment no. 2"
#newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
#newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment2)
#newMail.display()
newMail.Send()
```

System configuration details:

- Windows
- Python version : 3.9.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either call `newMail.Recipients.Add` for each address (it returns `Recipient` object, and you can set its `Type` property to `olTo` / `olCC` / `olBCC` if necessary - it defaults to `olTo`) or you can set `newMail.To` / `CC` /`BCC` properties to a list of ";" separated names or address.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Could you please provide the code snippet for the same for setting the Type property as you have mentioned in the comment , it will be a great help. Also it would be quite very helpful if you could provide the documentation for this module. Thanks

Comment: `recip = newMail.Recipients.Add("user@domain.demo")  recip.Type = 2` here 2 is olCC

Comment: Thanks , but in case of group having more than 10 email id, how should we add this. Do we need to use Add() for all the mail ids individually?

Comment: Yes. Or concatenate all 10 emails into a `;` separated string and assign it to the To, CC, or BCC property.